# Auction period using block.number

Tags: block-interval, auctions

I have something like:

```
   contract example{
            uint endBlock;
            constructor(uint _elitism) public {
                endBlock= block.number + 40; // 10 min of time
            }
        
            modifier onlyBeforeEnd() {
                require(block.number  > endBlock, "Auction already ended.");
                _;
            }

            function getBalance() onlyBeforeEnd public view returns(uint){
                return msg.sender.balance;
            }
        
    }
```

if I try to execute `getBalance()` fuction, everytime it get: "Auction already ended." But, why? The auction is supposed to last 10 minutes.

---

could anybody help me, please?

Comment: May anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> everytime it get: "Auction already ended." But, why?

The `require()` statement in the modifier is incorrect.

```
require(block.number  > endBlock, "Auction already ended.");
        ^                      ^  ^                      ^
        +---------- A ---------+  +---------- B ---------+
```

The `require()` statement requires that A is true for code execution to continue. If A is not true, then error B is returned.

A is not true until after the end of the auction. If you are running `getBalance()` before the end of the auction, A is false, and error B is returned.